# Change height for TabbedPage

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created custom render for my Tabbar. Now I want to increase the height. Not sure where can I change the height. Because the text are trimmed.

[image]

In my MainActivity.cs

> TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.CustomTabbar;

My styles.xml

```
  <style name="CustomTab"
        parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">500sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  </style>
```

My CustomTabbar.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF3300"  
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTab"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Edit: Added minHeight but the label are not showing as whole.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `android:minHeight` for the `TabLayout`.

The code of the TabLayout for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="200dp"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF3300"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

**Update:**

Change:

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

To:

```
 app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

Comment: I added the minHeight but I thought it will fixed the issue the label is not showing as whole. I updated my question.

Comment: Actually, the width could not show all the label when you use long title. If you want to make it possible, make the `TabLayout` scrollable. Check my update.